# How can I delete all alerts for a user in Sharepoint 2007 without visiting every site?

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2007, alerts

A user leaves the organisation.  Their account is removed from active directory.  Their user object does not get removed from Sharepoint, and their alerts remain in place.  This generates undeliverable messages each time an alert is sent to the email address in Sharepoint.

How can I tidy up all the alerts for a given user, without having to visit each site and remove the alerts for that user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[I created a script to do this using PowerShell](http://www.dunxd.com/2010/12/delete-all-alerts-for-a-user-in-sharepoint-with-this-powershell-script/).  Comments appreciated, and if anyone has a better way, I'd really like to know.